# Is it possible to write a text file in such a way that when read by the Java compiler, it will add a line break at certain points?

Tags: java, file, printing, format, bufferedreader

For my Java class, I'm working on a project that is essentially a database for MTG cards. I have to read from a file as part of the project, so I am reading the card information from a file, and then splitting the lines to put each different type of information together to form different object classes for the different types of cards. The main nitpicky issue I'm running into right now is that I need the card text to be on one line in the text file so I can read it line by line, but I'd prefer if it weren't all on one line when I print it to the console. Is there any way to add a character combination into the text of the file itself that will tell my compiler, "line break here," when it reads that, or am I out of luck? I know I could just use \n in the code to achieve this, but as I am looping through the file, there is no way to do so properly that I know of, as not every card's text needs line breaks inserted. If it matters, this is the chunk of my code that deals with that:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MTG {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int creatureLength = 4;
        //Prompt User
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Magic: the Gathering card database. This tool currently supports Rare and Mythic Rare cards from the Throne of Eldraine Expansion.");

        try {
                System.out.println("\nSelect the card type you'd like to view.");
                System.out.println(""
                        + "(1)Creatures\n"
                        );
                int choice = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());

                //Choose type   
                //Creatures
                if(choice == 1){
                    Creature[] creatures = creatureGen("textfiles/Creatures.txt", creatureLength);
                    System.out.println("\nViewing creatures. Which card would you like to view?: \n");
                    for(int k = 0; k < creatureLength; k++) {
                        System.out.println(
                                "(" + (k + 1) + ") " + creatures[k].getName());
                    }
                    int creatureChoice = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
                    try {
                        System.out.println("\n" + creatures[(creatureChoice - 1)]);}
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Input was not a specified number. Exiting...");
                    }
                }   
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            System.out.println("Input was not a specified number. Exiting...");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
    //Read Creature text file
    public static Creature[] creatureGen(String path, int length) {
        Creature[] creatures = new Creature[length];
        try {
            FileReader file = new FileReader(path);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
            String name[] = new String[length];
            String cost[] = new String[length];
            String color[] = new String[length];
            String type[] = new String[length];
            String cTypes[] = new String[length];
            String tags[] = new String[length];
            String text[] = new String[length];
            int power[] = new int[length];
            int toughness[] = new int[length];

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                if(line != null) {
                    name[i] = line.split("\\|")[0];
                    cost[i] = line.split("\\|")[1];
                    color[i] = line.split("\\|")[2];
                    type[i] = line.split("\\|")[3];
                    cTypes[i] = line.split("\\|")[4];
                    tags[i] = line.split("\\|")[5];
                    text[i] = line.split("\\|")[6];
                    power[i] = Integer.parseInt(line.split("\\|")[7]);
                    toughness[i] = Integer.parseInt(line.split("\\|")[8]);
                    creatures[i] = new Creature(name[i], cost[i], color[i], type[i], cTypes[i], tags[i], text[i], power[i], toughness[i]);
                    }
                }
            reader.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error reading file: " + path);
            }
        return creatures;
    }
}
```

The Creature object class essentially just stores the data that I am putting into it with the creatureGen method. A sample line from the text file I am reading from looks something like this:

```
Charming Prince|1W|White|Creature|Human Noble||When Charming Prince enters the battlefield, choose one — • Scry 2. • You gain 3 life. • Exile another target creature you own. Return it to the battlefield under your control at the beginning of the next end step.|2|2
```

It would be ideal to be able to insert line breaks after each of the bullet points in this card, for example, but as I said earlier, I need the text to be in one line for my loop to read it. Is there any way around this when I print this back to the console? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Just for terminology: *"when read by the java compiler"* sounds fancy but does not make any sense. The code is firstly **compiled** (not "read by the java compiler") and then executed / run. During that you want to code to do something, just state it as such: *"Is it possible to add a line break at certain points?"* to which the answer clearly is **yes**, quite easily. By simply reading the data, finding the points at which you want to insert a newline and then doing just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace those bullet points with line breaks :

```
text[i] = line.split("\\|")[6].replaceAll("•","\n");
```

Also, you should not split each time you need an element, put the result of line.split("\|") in a String[] variable and use it afterwards.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if(line != null) {
                String[] elements = line.split("\\|");
                name[i] = elements[0];
                cost[i] = elements[1];
                color[i] = elements[2];
                type[i] = elements3];
                cTypes[i] = elements[4];
                tags[i] = elements[5];
                text[i] = elements[6].replaceAll("•","\n");
                power[i] = Integer.parseInt(elements[7]);
                toughness[i] = Integer.parseInt(elements[8]);
                creatures[i] = new Creature(name[i], cost[i], color[i], type[i], cTypes[i], tags[i], text[i], power[i], toughness[i]);
                }
            }
```

Finally, about vocabulary, the compiler is not reading your file. The compiler translates your code into binary instructions for the processor (to summarize).
Your file is read at runtime.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it was helpful ?

Comment: Sorry, still new to the site! Accepted it now. Thanks again